# ERR: pom.xml Unknown lifecycle phase "package;"

Tags: xml, maven, pom.xml

```
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "package;". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
```

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.socgen.portfolio</groupId>
<artifactId>portfolio</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>ui</module>
    <module>service</module>
</modules>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

POM.xml[UI]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.socgen.portfolio</groupId>
<artifactId>ui</artifactId>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.socgen.portfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>portfolio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/d3js -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>d3js</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

POM.xml[Service]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.socgen.portfolio</groupId>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.socgen.portfolio</groupId>
    <artifactId>portfolio</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Im not able to import the dependencies can someone help me in this?
and not even to import any of the modules its giving the above mentioned error while importing the dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont use a semicolon.

It looks like you called `mvn package;` instead of `mvn package`